# add spring project to gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I am working on a spring project, and I want to use GitLab so I can work with my team.
The problem is, I don't how to add my spring project to GitLab.
I tried adding README file, and it worked for me.

I got the following error :  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Here's screen capture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your current dir is not a git repo. You can see hidden files by running ls -all. A git repo is defined by a .git/ hidden folder somewhere at or above your current working directory.  You must change dir to where you initialized your repository i.e. where you made the README file and move your spring project into that directory.

At that point you can add file(s) to staging using the git add command and then commit.